# Unity3D: When are transition conditions evaluated

Tags: animation, graphics, unity-game-engine

I have a very simple game running in Unity, and unfortunately, it is not working as expected.

### The Context

I have the following setup:

[image]
<sub>(source: [mazyod.com](http://mazyod.com/images/Screenshot_2014-04-23_10.51.20.png))</sub>

From any state, if an integer parameter `direction` is equal to `1`, set animation `player_move_e`. Same goes for `2`, `3`, `4` for the other directions. Once `direction` is set to `0`, the idle animation associated with the direction is played.

**An important thing to point here** is, since I am using the "Any State" block, I must make sure that once the animation state changes to one of the move animation states, I reset `direction` to sentinel value, like `-1`, that keeps the animation state in the current state, and not change states to itself again.

### The Problem

When the player is in the, say, `move_n` state, and I quickly change the direction to the, say, `move_e` (not giving it enough time to transition to idle), the animation state is stuck at the `move_n` :(

How can I know if the transition happened, and I am not updating too often? Initially, I was updating `direction` in `FixedUpdate`, and then moved it to `Update`, but it's the same issue in both methods.

Here is the logic I am seeing:

```
// MY CODE
animator.SetInteger(1); // Initially, it's move_e
...
// WITHIN UNITY (making it up)
Unity.UpdateStates(); // The number is read in the engine, and transition happens
...
// MY CODE
animator.SetInteger(-1); // Stay at current animation
...
// WITHIN UNITY (making it up)
Unity.UpdateStates(); // The number is read in the engine, nothing should happen
...
// MY CODE
animator.SetInteger(0); // The logic briefly changes to idle
...
// WITHIN UNITY (making it up)
Unity.UpdateStates(); // The number is read in the engine, transition to idle
...
// MY CODE
animator.SetInteger(4); // transition to north
...
// WITHIN UNITY (making it up)
// NOTHING HAPPENS!! It doesn't catch up
...
// MY CODE
animator.SetInteger(-1); // Stay at current state, assuming it changed to move_n
...
// WITHIN UNITY (making it up)
Unity.UpdateStates(); // The number is read in the engine, stays at idle_e!
...
```

#### UPDATE:

Here is the whole code:

```
void Update()
{
    // update animator (Stupid transition from any state includes current state -_-")
    int heading = CalculateHeading(horizontalInput, verticalInput);

    if (heading != previousHeading)
    {
        anim.SetInteger("direction", heading);
        previousHeading = heading;
    }
    else
    {
        anim.SetInteger("direction", -heading);
    }
}

void MovementManagement ()
{
    // If there is some axis input...
    if(horizontalInput != 0f || verticalInput != 0f)
    {
        Vector3 position = transform.position;
        position.x += horizontalInput * movementSpeed;
        position.y += verticalInput * movementSpeed;

        transform.position = position;
    }
}

int CalculateHeading(float horizontal, float vertical)
{
    if (horizontal == 0f && vertical == 0f)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    if (Mathf.Abs(horizontal) > Mathf.Abs(vertical))
    {
        return (horizontal > 0 ? 1 : 3);
    }
    else
    {
        return (vertical > 0 ? 4 : 2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you changing the int value several times during one `Update()` call? Maybe some of your real code would help to find the problem

Comment: @Leosori I felt I was missing something... Will update with code now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I built a small scene for myself and played around a little bit. I could reproduce your problem and even found a simple solution.

**Why it happens**

The problem seems to occur when the animator state machine is still in transition to a new state. During that time, new parameter values are ignored but your code is going to change that value again in the next `update()` call. The state machine ignored your new direction and now only sees a value for which it has no transition available, `direction = -1` for example.

The default behavior for transitions is `atomic` which means according to the [reference](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Components/class-Transition.html) that it cannot be interrupted. However, setting it to false made no difference... It could be a bug and you may want to file a bug report.

**Solution**

You need to check if the state machine is currently in a transition by checking [`IsInTransition(int layer)`](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Animator.IsInTransition.html) like this:

```cs
void Update()
{
    // update animator (Stupid transition from any state includes current state -_-")
    int heading = CalculateHeading(horizontalInput, verticalInput);

    if (heading != previousHeading && !anim.IsInTransition(0))  // you may need to adjust the layer index
    {
        anim.SetInteger("direction", heading);
        previousHeading = heading;
    }
    else
    {
        anim.SetInteger("direction", -heading);
    }
}
```

**Another possible solution**

I don't know what kind of animations you are using for the different directions, but it may be easier to use one animation and just turn your character around :) This way you have less transitions and states and it may be easier to add more animations later on.

Comment: Thanks so much for this! I actually tried unchecking atomic myself, and was like, "Yay, I am so smart :3", only to be disappointed with the result. I am using 2D sprites, so can't really turn 2D sprites :P ... It's super disheartening that this is the second bug I came across... I started Unity 2 days ago!!!